# How do I know whether a function is continuous at every number in its domain?

Tags: limits, functions

> For example, this function, $g(x) = 3 \sqrt{x}(1+x^3)$,

How do I know whether a function is continuous at every number in its domain?

Comment: Let $x$ be any element in the domain.  What definition have you been taught, about whether the function is continuous at $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c \in D$ be arbitrary, where $D$ is the domain of the function $g$. Then, verify continuity with whatever definition of continuity you know. If the verification goes through, and you did not have to make any further assumption about $c$, then since your choice of $c$ was arbitrary, the function is continuous at every element of its domain (or just continuous for short). Sometimes, it is useful to partition the domain and do the above for each partition.

In your case, $g(x) = 3\sqrt{x}(1 + x^3)$. This function is only defined for $x \in [0, \infty)$. Thus, let $c \in [0, \infty)$. Then, using the limit definition,

$$
\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = \lim_{x \to c} 3\sqrt{x}(1 + x^3) = 3 \sqrt{c}(1 + c^3) = g(c).
$$
Note that in the second equality I used the facts that $\sqrt{x}$ and $(1 + x^3)$ are continuous on the same domain (one can in turn use the same principles to prove these facts by exploiting some known facts about limits, or the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity). Since $c$ was chosen arbitrarily, and I did not assume anything else about $c$, $g$ is continuous at every element of its domain.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.
Since the multiplication for continuous functions is continuous, you know $g$ is continuous as square root and polynomials are continuous for $x\geq 0$.

The more straightforward way is to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuous functions(assume you learned it).

One last way is to use an online graphing calculator(though not rigorous, it will give you an idea of what the graph looks like).